# Inequity problem of polynomial and exponential

Tags: inequality

I am solving the following problem:

$1 \le {x \over n} + \left( {n-1} \over n \right)^x$

$x$ and $n$ are positive integers

I tried to generalize the inequation by assigning values from 1 to ?, but fails to do that.

Comment: Check Bernoulli's Inequality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
It is equivalent to prove that 
$$(1-\frac{1}{n})^x\geq1-\frac{x}{n}$$ for $x$ and $n$ are integers.